# How do you correctly format a new table that is pulling from another table while creating constraints in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Below I created a table with primary key, foreign key, an not null constraints however I keep receiving the error

> "%s: invalid identifier"

CREATE TABLE writers
    ((authorid VARCHAR2(4), 
    lastname VARCHAR2(10), 
    firstname VARCHAR2(10), 
    isbn VARCHAR2(10), 
    title VARCHAR2(30)),
    (CONSTRAINT wt_pk PRIMARY KEY (authorid),
    CONSTRAINT wt_nn NOT NULL (title),
    CONSTRAINT wt_fk FOREIGN KEY (isbn) REFERENCES books (isbn)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create table then try doing insert into select.

```
CREATE TABLE writers
(
    authorid <datatype>, 
    last name <datatype>, 
    first name <datatype>, 
    isbn <datatype>, 
    title <datatype>,  
    CONSTRAINT wt_pk PRIMARY KEY (authorid),
    CONSTRAINT wt_nn NOT NULL (title),
    CONSTRAINT wt_fk FOREIGN KEY (isbn) REFERENCES books (isbn)
) ;

insert into writers (authorid, last name, first name, isbn, title)
SELECT authorid, fname, lname, isbn, title 
     FROM author 
     JOIN bookauthor USING (authorid)
     JOIN books USING (isbn);
```

Comment: I updated my original post with what you recommended but I am still receiving invalid identifier @AmeyaN99

Comment: CREATE TABLE writers 
(authorid VARCHAR2(4), 
lastname VARCHAR2(10), 
firstname VARCHAR2(10), 
isbn VARCHAR2(10), 
title VARCHAR2(30),
CONSTRAINT wt_pk PRIMARY KEY (authorid), 
CONSTRAINT wt_nn NOT NULL (title), 
CONSTRAINT wt_fk FOREIGN KEY (isbn) REFERENCES books (isbn));

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't let you specify the table definition with `as`.  So, create the table first and then add the constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE writers as
    SELECT authorid, fname, lname, isbn, title
    FROM author JOIN
         bookauthor
         USING (authorid) JOIN
         books
         USING (isbn);

ALTER TABLE writers
    ADD CONSTRAINT wt_pk PRIMARY KEY (authorid);
ALTER TABLE writers
    ADD CONSTRAINT wt_nn NOT NULL (title);
ALTER TABLE writers
    ADD CONSTRAINT wt_fk FOREIGN KEY (isbn) REFERENCES books (isbn);
```

Presumably, you actually want the primary key constraing on `(authorid, isbn)` rather than just `authorid`.

Comment: When I add the constraints after creating the table I then receive "invalid ALTER TABLE option"

Comment: @Mitch . . . Some databases allow multiple changes in `alter table`, but Oracle is not one of them.  That should be three separate statements.

Comment: With this method I violate the primary key constraint as I have duplicates in the data table:                                                                                                    cannot validate (%s.%s) - primary key violated"
*Cause:    attempted to validate a primary key with duplicate values or null
           values.
*Action:   remove the duplicates and null values before enabling a primary
           key.

Comment: @Mitch . . . Well, then you don't want those constraints, if the data doesn't comply.  This is presumably the primary key constraint.